# Hiding div also hides image of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide a menu called chooseArena inside a larger div called header.   When I hide chooseArena it also hides the image of the larger div.  What do I do so I only hide the smaller div and not the image of the larder div.

Here is my html jquery

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dojo Arena</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').hover(function(){
            var arena = $(this).attr('id');
            var id = arena + '.jpg';
            $('#header').css('background-image', 'url('+id+')');
        }, function(){
            $('#header').css('background-image', 'none');
        });
        $('button').click(function(){
            var arena = $(this).attr('id');
            var id = arena + '.jpg';
            $('#header').css('background-image', 'url('+id+')');
            $('#chooseArena').hide();  // This also hides the image above.  What do I change so it will only hide the div and not the parent div with the background img
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id = "chooseArena">
            <h1>Choose an Arena</h1>
            <button id = "dojo">Dojo</button>
            <button id = "beach">Beach</button>
            <button id = "earth">Earth</button>
            <button id = "matrix">Matrix</button>
            <button id = "snow">Snow</button>
            <button id = "forest">Forest</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css file

```
*{
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#chooseArena{
    border: 1px solid: red;
    margin-left: 40%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-top: 20%;
}

button{
    background-color: white;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h1{
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: 20%;
}

#header{
    height: 900px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    padding-top: 5%;
}

option{
    background-color: white;
}

select{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('#chooseArena').css("opacity","0");
```

My guess is that hiding the div, meaning making it "display: none" sets the header height and width to `auto` and therefore you can't see the background image.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `#chooseArena` is the only child of `#header`. By default, a block level element (`#header`) will only be as tall as the children inside. If it has no children inside, it's height will be `0`. So when you remove `#childArena` from `#header`, `#header`'s height is now 0. And the "image" in `#header` is a background image, so it will only show if `#header` is also shown on the page. A background image will not take up any space or cause any height to be applied to the element it's assigned to.

One way to fix this would be to set `opacity: 0;` or `visibility: hidden;` on `#chooseArena` (instead of hiding it with `display: none` or `$.hide()`), which will hide `#chooseArena` visually on the page, but `#chooseArena` will still take up space in `#header` like they it isn't hidden.

If that doesn't work, you can still hide `#chooseArena` but also give `#header` a `height` value to match whatever the height of the background image is or how you want that background image to display.

Comment: So If I have another child element, the img will not disappear?

Comment: @Aaron if you add another child element and it has positioning that causes `#header` to have layout, then `#header` will have a height. Try adding a simple `p` or `div` tag with some text or an actual `img` element or something, and you'll see that `#header` will obey the height of that element when `#chooseArena` is hidden. That's not to say that the background image on `#header` will be fully visible - that depends on the way the background image was implemented and the size of whatever child you add to `#header`